# Android multitouch resize listview font

Tags: android, scale, pinchzoom

I have a ScaleGestureDetector below and I can detect the onScale event and resize my View in real-time after calling the adpater notifyDataSetChanged.
However, it is slow because my view is complex.
Is there any way to capture a temp image of the view and then do the image resize to show the effect to user and finally do the real final view data change when onScaleEnd fires ?

thanks a lot

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.java#ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener

Answer (score 0):

i achieve this by following

1. Save the bitmap

   this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

   ivSnapShotBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getDrawingCache());

   this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
2. onDraw(Canvas canvas)

   canvas.drawBitmap(ivSnapShotBitmap, 0, 0, null);

   canvas.scale(ivScaleFactor, ivScaleFactor);

   super.onDraw(canvas);

this can support API level of type 10 and below for multi-touch zoom because the view itselft doesn't support scale(x,y)

one problem of this is when the view is being scaled down. the empty space on right and bottom will show the original background, i am still finding way to fix it.